# Arrow function ambguity in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, arrow-functions

```
class Clock extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {date: new Date()};
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.timerID = setInterval(
      () => this.tick(),
      1000
    );
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.timerID);
  }

  tick() {
    this.setState({
      date: new Date()
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
        <h2>It is {this.state.date.toLocaleTimeString()}.</h2>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

In the above code - I wasn't able to understand the setInterval() line - to be precise the function argument of the setInterval line. I think it is an arrow function- I might be wrong. I replaced it with a regular function `setInterval(function(){this.tick()},1000)` and got an error saying tick() is not a function. What's happening here?

Comment: I think you don't have to create a new function there at all. Just do `this.tick` (without the brackets) instead of `() => this.tick()` and it should work

Comment: @Volper I think that might still run the risk of using the wrong `this` reference. Ideally we shouldn't use `setTimeout` or `setInterval` at all and instead should use a Delay Promise.

Comment: @Volper It returns error this.setState is not a function.

Comment: But a promise only resolves once, while setInterval calls a function many times

Comment: @ANIRUDH M S oh yeah that would require a binding too, so `this.tick.bind(this)` may work

Answer (score 5):

The `this` reference is reset when using old-style `function()` syntax, whereas with `=>` (arrow-functions) the `this` reference is preserved. You can still use `function()` but you need to call `.bind(this)` to "fix" the `this` reference.

So this:

```
this.timerID = setInterval(
    () => this.tick(),
    1000
);
```

Is equivalent to this:

```
this.timerID = setInterval(
    function() { this.tick(); }.bind(this),
    1000
);
```

You need to do this because `setTimeout`/`setInterval` is a member-property of the `global` (`window`) object, so inside a `setTimeout` or `setInterval` callback the `this` reference is for `window`, not the call-site's `this`.

Comment: Thanks- I got it